# Инші назви Грузії

Tags: власні-назви

З того що бачу, українцї [мали давнї стосунки](http://www.history.org.ua/?termin=Gruziya) з тим народом, щонайменше ще з часів Русї:

> <sub>Бібліографічне посилання: Ясь О.В. ГРУЗІЯ (Сакартвело) [Електронний ресурс] // Енциклопедія історії України: Т. 2: Г-Д / Редкол.: В. А. Смолій (голова) та ін. НАН України. Інститут історії України. - К.: В-во "Наукова думка", 2004. - 688 с.: іл..</sub>
>
> Україно-грузинські культурні, політичні та економічні відносини. Г. від середньовіччя підтримувала відносини з давньорус. та укр. землями. В 11 – на поч. 13 ст. Г. мала торг., госп. та культ. контакти з давньорус. князівствами, зокрема з поселеннями на Пн. Кавказі ([Біла Вежа](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0) (див. Саркел), Тмуторокань та ін.). Грузин. живописці брали участь у створенні мозаїки гол. церкви Києво-Печерської лаври (кін. 11 ст.). У 2-й пол. 12 ст. Г. та давньорус. князівства підтримують політ. взаємини: 1154 київ. кн. Ізяслав Мстиславич в останній рік життя вдруге одружився з дочкою грузин. царя Деметре I – Русудан. 1185 син владимиро-суздальського кн. Андрія Боголюбського Юрій одружився з грузин. царицею Тамар. Шлюб був розірваний через два роки.
>
> У 17 ст. на укр. землі з турец. неволі втікало чимало грузинів, які вливалися до лав Війська Запорозького. В 17 – на поч. 18 ст. грузин. князі підтримували зносини з запороз. козацтвом. Ширилися й культ. взаємини. Так, грузини, що мешкали в Москві в 1-й пол. 18 ст., переклали грузин. мовою тв. П.Могили та Димитрія Ростовського. У 30–40-х рр. 18 ст. царський уряд пожалував багатьом грузин. дворянським і княжим родинам (Абашидзе, Ерістовим, Жеваховим, Кекуатовим, Орбеліані, Тумановим та ін.) маєтки на тер. Лівобережної України, де був створений Грузин. гусарський полк. Протягом 18 – поч. 19 ст. грузин. дворяни поріднилися з укр. козацькою старшиною та її нащадками. Грузини в 1-й пол. 18 ст. селилися на землях Лубенського полку, Миргородського полку, Полтавського полку, Прилуцького полку та ін. полків. Грузин. поет Д.Гурамішвілі тривалий час мешкав і працював у Миргороді.

Сама ж назва *Грузія* скорїш за всього походить за посередництвом московської, щонайменше так твердить [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%93%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%96%D1%97):

> Російська назва *Грузия* перського походження, від перської گرجستان [*Gorjestân*] (турецькою: *Gürcistan*, осетинською: *Гуырдзыстон*, монгольською: *Гүрж*.)
>
> Російська назва вперше зустрічається в подорожніх записах Ігнатія Смольнянина як *гурзи* (1389):
>
> > А въ церковь ту влѣзщи, ино направѣ Гурзійскаа служба, Гурзіи служатъ. *- Хожение в Иерусалим*
>
> Афанасій Нікітін називає Грузію гурзинською землею (1466–72).
>
> > Да Севастѣи губѣ, да Гурзынской земли добро обилію всѣм; да Торская земля обилна. *- Хоженіе за три моря Афонасья Микитина*
>
> В результаті перестановки звуків *Гурз* перетворився на *Груз* і з часом *Груз-ія*. Російська назва була введена в кілька слов’янських мов (білоруська, болгарська, хорватська, чеська, македонська, польська, сербська, словацька, словенська, українська), а також інші мови, що історично контактували з Російською імперією та/або Радянським Союзом (наприклад, як латиська, литовська, естонська, угорська, їдиш, киргизька, туркменська, уйгурська, китайська, японська, корейська, в’єтнамська)

Тож чи є записи [які?] українською назов країни і народа?